# Column/Rowwise Rank in Armadillo

Tags: c++, sorting, linear-algebra, armadillo

I have an `arma::dmat X` of size `4` x `5`, and I need to compute the ranks columwise (or, equivalently, rowwise). That is, if `X` was given by

```
 1.7313004 -0.07725283  0.20853594 0.8234332  1.0856281
-1.5292486  1.37488968 -0.02532876 1.9258169  0.1119688 
-0.3280515 -0.26482346  1.09408275 1.5134836 -1.1991751 
-0.3365833 -0.34169977  0.94923045 0.8330554  1.7670869
```

then I want an `arma::umat R` that looks like this

```
4 3 3 1 2 
1 4 1 4 3
3 2 4 3 1
2 1 3 2 4
```

With `arma::sort_index` I was able to get the ranks for the matrix stacked columnwise, but this is not what I want. Of course, there is always the possibility to loop over each column and save the transformed column to a new matrix `R`. However, I was wondering whether there is a more elegant/more efficient solution than this.

Comment: Can you please explain the output? And what do you mean by rank?

Comment: The output (for each column) is index of the sorted values. Consider the first column: -1.529 ist the smallest values (hence it gets a 1), -0.336 is the second smallest value (so it gets a 2), and so on.

Comment: Did you try passing a matrix to this sort_index function? Does it throw any errors? If it doesn't work then maybe the answer to your question is NO.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, the sort_index function will stack the matrix to a vector

Comment: Can't you convert that vector back to matrix?

Comment: unfortunately not. The reason is that armadillo first stacks the columns, then computes the ranks (the ranks will range from 1 to 20 then instead of 1 to 4 as I would like to have it for the columnwise ranks).

Comment: Can you not transpose the matrix, sort, and then transpose the sorted result?

Comment: No, that also does not work, because (if transposed or not) sort_index will transform the matrix to a vector.